# Method as parameter with signature contract?

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to know how to create a contract with the caller for the Method parameter in the event the method has parameters itself.  So that I use...

```
ClassA {
  String string_ = "HI";

  public static void subscribe(Object class, Method action) {
    action.invoke(class, string_);
  }
}

ClassB {

  ClassB() {
    ClassA.subscribe(this, this.getClass().getMethod("load", String.class));
  }

  public void load(String input) {
    if(input.equals("HI")) { 
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to ensure the Method passed as "action" takes String as a parameter (i.e. ensure Method action == load(String){})?  Is there something like this available:

```
public static void subscribe(Object class, Method action(String.class)) {
```

I want to do it in the method signature of subscribe so that it is obvious to the calling class (ClassB) that it needs to be prepared to take an argument of specified type.

EDIT:  Updated last code bit so not to appear as if Method was generic.  Poor choice of using <> on my part to represent an example of what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that in Java. The Method class is not generic, and there is no way for it to be so, because methods can take any number of parameters, and there is no way to make a class generic over a variable number of types.

Probably the best you can do is to declare your own type to use instead of Method:

```
public interface Action<T, P> {
    public void invoke(T target, P parameter);
}
```

Then:

```
public static <T> void subscribe(T obj, Action<T, String> action) {
    action.invoke(obj, string_);
}

ClassB() {
    ClassA.subscribe(this, new Action<ClassB, String>() {
        public void invoke(ClassB target, String parameter) {
            target.load(parameter);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Laurent: True, but i a wise man once wrote "explicit is better than implicit", and my feeling is that declaring methods in interfaces is one of the times that's true.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer since it correctly answered that there was no way to do this in Java and why, and gave a possible solution.  Everyone seemed to use the command pattern in one way or another so I have them all a point up as a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there are means to achieve what you are trying to do but I can't think of a way to ensure that at compile time for java.

can you resort to using intefaces?

```
interface ILoader{
   void load(String input);
}

ClassA {
  String string_ = "HI";

  public static void subscribe(ILoader loader) {
    loader.load( string_);
  }
}

ClassB implements ILoader {

  ClassB() {
    ClassA.subscribe(this);
  }

  public void load(String input) {
    if(input.equals("HI")) { 
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use a slight modification of the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)?

```
puclic interface LoadCommand {
  public load(String input);
}

public class ClassB implements LoadCommand {
  public load(String input) {
    // do stuff here
  }
}

public class ClassA {

  String myInput = "HI";

  public static void subscribe(LoadCommand command) {
    command.load(myInput)
  }
}
```

The `load` method in the `LoadCommand` interface takes one `String` argument.

Comment: That's not quite Command, as i understand it, because the method on the Command interface is taking a parameter. Part of the point of of Command is that it's self-contained; anything parameter-like is already packed into the Command object.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: you're right. I changed my answer saying "a slight modification of the Command Pattern"